# Join a tribe as admin - Ark Survival Evolved

Tags: server-administration, ark-survival-evolved

So yesterday on my single player game I stupidly left my own tribe. The issue is that all the structures and Dino's were set to tribe owned and not personal owned.

How do I force to join the tribe again?

I have tried all the possible relevant commands in `ShowMyAdminManager`. I have also typed out all of the `ForcePlayerToJoinTribe (player ID from admin menu) "Tribe of Bob"` type commands.

I have also tried going up to a Dino or building and typing `ForcePlayerToJoinTargetTribe (my player ID)`

None of these commands work. I have tried creating a new tribe also called `Tribe of Bob`, all that happens is that the old tribe name is changed to `Tribe of Bob1`.

When I created the new **Tribe of Bob** I seemed to be allied with `Tribe of Bob1` because all the Dino and structure names were in light blue.

How can I forcibly join a target tribe using ark Commands? or any other solution that wont involve me losing all my work in the game.

Answer (score -1):

Just tried it, admincheat Forcejointribe